# How can I increment a counter and store the result in a variable in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Scripting and I need someone to help me to increment a counter and store the result in a variable in

Comment: I tested below code but no luck   counter = counter + 1 but it's not incrementing Counter

Comment: What does this have to do with iphone? Updating tags...

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of what you've tried?  Narrow down the problem to a complete runnable script which demonstrates the issue, and indicate what behavior you observe when running the script.

Answer (score 1):

A counter can be incremented using a keyword 'Next'

```
Dim Subject
For Subject = 1 to 4
 Msgbox “English Paper:” & val & “<br />”
Next
```

Output:

> English Paper:1
>   English Paper:2
>   English Paper:3
>   English Paper:4

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this set you in the right direction, you need to define values for X, Y and count.

```
for X to Y
count = count + 1
Next

wscript.echo (count)
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply